# Template is missing, after creating scaffold and database in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates

I get the following error. 
**Template is missing**

```
Missing template jobs/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :handlers=>[:builder, :erb, :coffee], :formats=>[:html]}. Searched in: * "/Users/anderskitson/projects/easyjobs/app/views"
```

I added 2 gems

gem 'haml'

gem 'haml-rails'

and ran bundle.

I also created a database and ran the following, not sure why I get template missing.

```
rails g scaffold job title:string description:text company_name:string details_link:string
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your handlers do not include haml. Have you restarted the server?